# PHP: get/parse multiple part of string to Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match-all

I want to parse HTML elements properties to Array. in the example in 2 line have 2 objects:

```
<?php

    $str='<label>First name: <input type=text name=firstname /></label>\n<label>Last name: <input type=text name=lastname /></label>\n';
    $i=1;
    $start[1]="type=";
    $end[1]=" ";

    preg_match_all('/'.$start[$i].'(.*?)'.$end[1].'/i', $str, $item->type);

    var_dump($output);

?>
```

in this case the query should be `$item->type[1][1]` to resulting "TEXT" as input type.
but i need something like this: `$item[1]->type`

The final result should be a PlainHTML2DrupalWebformImportableXML converter.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are parsing HTML, I suggest you use **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm